# Unable to get the right timing in execute anything after Multiple Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

why can't i get the right output?
this my Code:

=======

1.Main

```
public class ThreadDebut {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
     PrintDemo PD = new PrintDemo();
     List<ThreadDemo> th = new ArrayList<ThreadDemo>();
     ThreadDemo T1 = new ThreadDemo( "Thread - 1 ", PD );
     ThreadDemo T2 = new ThreadDemo( "Thread - 2 ", PD );


     T1.start();
     th.add(T1);
     T2.start();
     th.add(T2);

     for(ThreadDemo t : th) {
         try {
            t.join();
         }catch( Exception e) {
           System.out.println("Interrupted");
         }
     }
   System.out.println("\n\n\n");
   }
}
```

2.Thread and method

```
 class PrintDemo {
   public void printCount() {
      try {
         for(int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
            System.out.println("Counter   ---   "  + i );
         }
      }catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Thread  interrupted.");
      }
   }
}

class ThreadDemo extends Thread {
   private Thread t;
   private String threadName;
   PrintDemo  PD;

       ThreadDemo( String name,  PrintDemo pd) {
      threadName = name;
          PD = pd;
       }

       public void run() {
          synchronized(PD) {
             PD.printCount();
          }
          System.out.println("Thread " +  threadName + " exiting.");
       }

   public void start () {
      System.out.println("Starting " +  threadName );
      if (t == null) {
         t = new Thread (this, threadName);
         t.start ();
      }
   }
}
```

i mean i want to get this *System.out.println("\n\n\n");* after both thread done executing. But, all i get was random after the before synchronized things of thread 1. i have do thread.join() but failed. Why? someone explain to me please... thanks and regards!!!

Comment: I few suggestions:  * You're adding the threads to ph after you've started them.  * You're synchronizing on the same object (PD). * You're catching errors bu assuming they are all Interruptions  * [minor] ThreadDemo should really implement Runnable rather than extend Thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to both subclass and use a delegate at the same time. You essentaly create two threads for every thread. Instead of using a delegate you should be overriding the methods of Thread. Like so:

```
static class ThreadDemo extends Thread {
    private String threadName;
    PrintDemo PD;

    ThreadDemo (String name, PrintDemo pd) {
        threadName = name;
        PD = pd;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (PD) {
            PD.printCount();
        }
        System.out.println("Thread " + threadName + " exiting.");
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Starting " + threadName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you are not using ThreadDemo class as a subclass of Thread. You create another Thread t inside your ThreadDemo. If you want to use the join method, you have to add an adapter method as following:

```
static class ThreadDemo extends Thread {
    private Thread t;
    private String threadName;
    PrintDemo PD;

    ThreadDemo(String name, PrintDemo pd) {
        threadName = name;
        PD = pd;
    }

    public void run() {
        synchronized (PD) {
            PD.printCount();
        }
        System.out.println("Thread " + threadName + " exiting.");
    }

    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Starting " + threadName);
        if (t == null) {
            t = new Thread(this, threadName);
            t.start();
        }
    }

    public void join1() {
        try {
            t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```